# How to set a model variable in a view to a value from within javascript inside a $("form").submit function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am trying to deal with timezone issues I am having while using bootstrap-datetimepicker for my method of GUI input from the user.

I can not find a way to get the FromDate value to update in the model with the adjusted UTC time.

Having trouble formatting my html code in here for some reason, so I will try to describe it in parts

```
<form action="Url.Action...new { id = Model.ListingCurrent.ID }) })" method="post" role="form">
<div class="input-group center-block" id="datetimepicker">
...
input type text id="FromDate"
input type text id="ToDate"
```

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
debugger;
$(function () {
    $('#FromDate').datetimepicker({
        stepping: 20
    });
});
$(function () {
    $('#ToDate').datetimepicker({
        stepping: 20
    });
});

$("form").submit(function () {
    //var input = $('#FromDate').val();
    $("#FromDate").val = getUTCDate(input);        
});

function getUTCDate() {
    var shite = moment($('#FromDate').val()).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZZ');
    return shite
}
```

UPDATE:  Tried this code
The result is taking me back to my input text box datetimepicker GUI

```
    $("form").submit(function () {
    var input = $('#FromDate').val();
    var test1 = getUTCDate(input);
    var test2 = $('#FromDate').val(test1);
});
```

Here is debugging in Chrome F12 tools

```
$("form").submit(function () {
    var input = $('#FromDate').val(); input = "01/27/2016 1:20 AM"
    var test1 = getUTCDate(input); test1 = "2016-01-27T06:20:00+0000"
    var test2 = $('#FromDate').val(test1); test2 = [input#FromDate.form-control, context: document, selector: "#FromDate"]
});
```

UPDATE:
STATE: When ran in browser after picking dates and hitting submit, the user is directed back to the input text rather than being submitted to the controller.

```
    $("form").submit(function () {
    var input = $('#FromDate').val();
    var test1 = getUTCDate(input);
    $('#FromDate').val(test1);
    //var test2 = $('#FromDate').val(test1);
});
```

UPDATE:

```
$('#FromDate').text = utcTime;
```

.text gets the value I need into #FromDate but it is not passing into my controller.  What is passing into my controller is this variable in the view model with the value that I put in the Text Input in the browser.

I am thinking this may be a jquery validation thing perhaps.
This is the warning I get in the browser debugger when it takes me back to the input

at HTMLFormElement.eval (eval at evaluate (unknown source), :1:2)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (:875:55)

Comment: I have tried setting it like so as well
document.getDocumentId("FromDate".value = input;

Comment: should be `.val(getUTCDate(input))`

Comment: No Bueno :(
My controller
public async Task<ActionResult> Order(Order order)

order is showing the value I put in the input box still, it is not returning the updated value after it runs through the getUTCDate method

Comment: Actually looks like I have an error, I will try to debug and report back.
"Uncaught ReferenceError: input is not defined"

Comment: test2 = $('#FromDate').val(test1); this assigns the jQuery object to test2 var, no the value. Split in two lines first .val(xx); second test2=$...val(); to see the value in test 2

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  I still get sent back to the text input on the browser when I hit submit.

Comment: Could someone please comment on the etiquette here - should I update my original posting code to reflect changes as part of the troubleshooting process here?  My concern is that information is lost and that the comments will no longer make sense for new viewers.

Comment: Passing a value to the .val() function always results in [input#FromDate.form-control, context: document, selector: "#FromDate"] and not a real value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a combination of validation and the formatting of the date.

The date wasn't in the proper format for the validation on the input fields

```
data-rule-required="true" data-rule-date="true"
```

This would cause the validation routine to kick in and bring me back to my form every time I actually had a date passed back in the variable.

This was a shit show, I don't blame the moderators if they delete this.  I'm not sure what anyone else can really learn from this.

Thanks for everyone's time to tried to help.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$(function(){
    $('form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //Prevent the form submitting with the old values
        $('#FromDate').val(getUTCDate($('#FromDate').val()); //Change the form value

        this.submit(); //Re-submit the form with the updated values
                       //No jQuery was used to prevent an infinite loop ;)
    });
});
```